# javascript fuction confusion?

Tags: javascript, html

How does the function getSubTotal know that there is 4 items? I know isays itemCount*7.5 but where is the code that establishes the itemCount?

```
var orderCount = 0;

function takeOrder(topping, crustType) {
  console.log('Order: ' + crustType + ' crust topped with ' + topping);
  orderCount = orderCount + 1;
}

function getSubTotal(itemCount) {
  return itemCount * 7.5;
}

takeOrder('bacon', 'thin');
takeOrder('pepperoni', 'regular');
takeOrder('pesto', 'thin');
takeOrder('pesto','ronii');

console.log(getSubTotal(orderCount));
```

Comment: you're passing in `orderCount` which is storing 4 based on the `takeOrder` function. This is a very basic question which should really be known if you watched/read some tutorials

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. It is a codeacademy javascript tutorial I got this from. I will learn.

Comment: The reason why orderCount gets incremented as it's declared as a global variable. and is incremented 4 times as `takeOrder` is called four times before `getSubTotal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orderCount is set to 0, and increased to 4 after calling function takeOrder 4 times.

Then it is passed to function getSubTotal as input, so in this case, the itemCount is the same as the orderCount, which is 4